# Extending TFS, add signature to fields on keycombo

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'd like to extend tfs, so that when I hit a specific key combo, it enters in my name and the current date into whatever text field I have the cursor currently in.

Is there a way to do this?

I was able to get Resharper to do this in code, but that doesn't' work in TFS (Darn you to heck Resharper!)

I'm running vs2013, and it's Team Explorer 2013 as well

Comment: What do you mean "in TFS"?  TFS is a server product, with many client applications that interact with it's services (e.g. visual studio, MTM, TFS Web Access, etc).

Comment: In visual studio on the TFS related tabs (in particular on the large comment boxes on the work item screens)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to create a Visual Studio Extension to do this.  You can read about how to do that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd885119.aspx